# How do I apply texture on canvas image webgl?

Tags: webgl, layer

I have one base image and created layers for that. Layers are png images.

I could load canvas.drawImage to add layers with base image. But how can i apply texture on layer image without changing layer size.

Like, I want render image on another image in webgl.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know exactly what effect you want to achieve, but i think that fragment shader will help you with that, try to put this code into [shadertoy editor](https://www.shadertoy.com/):

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;        
    fragColor = texture2D(iChannel1, uv) * texture2D(iChannel0, uv);
}
```

And do not forget to put some textures to iChannel0 and iChannel1, so it looks like this:
[image]

Yeah and i forget about those articles, they should also help you a lot:
[WebGL image processing](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html) and [WebGL using 2 or more textures](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2-textures.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I got it work on canvas with overlay images.